# npm install error p2, other modules are normally

Tags: node.js, npm, p2

Don't install npm module p2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/p2

```
npm install --save --no-bin-links p2
```

Tried

```
npm install --save --no-bin-links git+ssh://git@github.com:schteppe/p2.js.git
```

The result is the same.

**npm-debug.log**
https://gist.github.com/instantia/e0c323903ee4edd06274

What could be the problem?

Comment: **ERROR:**
https://gist.github.com/instantia/5a9f6864cbb601dc798f

Comment: `npm cache clean` does not solve my problem

Comment: I suspect that the error resides in one of the dependencies... Can you install https://github.com/schteppe/poly-decomp.js ? Or https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/process-nextick-args ?

Answer (score 0):

So, as vagrant not fixed a bug UNC path Windows.
My solution was:
vagrant shell script

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "scripts/mounts.sh", run: "always"
```

mounts.sh

```
echo "Mounting node_modules to home folder"
mkdir -p ~/www/dev/roamforge/node_modules && mkdir -p /vagrant/www/dev/roamforge/node_modules && sudo mount -o bind ~/www/dev/roamforge/node_modules /vagrant/www/dev/roamforge/node_modules
```